# grafico ajax en python

Tags: html, python, pandas

me gustaría saber si existe alguna posibilidad de insertar un gráfico con una respuesta ajax que me devuelve dos campos con distintos datos, es decir, nombre: {juan,pedro,gabriel}, apellido{5,10,3}. Utilizo el f.write para que me cree un archivo .html.
No adjunto nada de código porque no se como empezar, gracias.

Comment: Pides datos con JS, python te responde con un json y graficas usando alguna librería de JS

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es posible insertar un gráfico en un archivo HTML utilizando una respuesta AJAX que devuelve datos en dos campos distintos. Puedes utilizar una biblioteca de JavaScript como D3.js o Highcharts para crear el gráfico a partir de los datos devueltos por la respuesta AJAX. Una vez que tengas los datos en formato adecuado, puedes insertar el gráfico en el archivo HTML utilizando el método .write() de JavaScript para escribir el código necesario en el archivo.

aquí te dejo un ejemplo hipotético de cómo podría ser el código para insertar un gráfico en un archivo HTML utilizando una respuesta AJAX y la biblioteca D3.js:

```
// Primero, realizamos la petición AJAX para obtener los datos del gráfico
$.ajax({
  url: '/mi-url-ajax',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // Una vez que obtenemos los datos, los procesamos para adaptarlos al formato necesario
    // para crear el gráfico con D3.js
    var datos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.nombres.length; i++) {
      datos.push({
        nombre: data.nombres[i],
        apellido: data.apellidos[i]
      });
    }

    // Creamos un nuevo gráfico utilizando D3.js
    var chart = d3.select('#mi-contenedor-grafico')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);

    // Añadimos los datos al gráfico
    chart.selectAll('mi-elemento')
      .data(datos)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) { return i * 50; })
      .attr('y', function(d) { return 500 - d.apellido; })
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('height', function(d) { return d.apellido; });
  }
});

// Luego, utilizamos el método .write() de JavaScript para insertar el código del gráfico en el archivo HTML
f.write('<div id="mi-contenedor-grafico"></div>');
```

Este es un ejemplo muy básico y supone que tienes un elemento  con el ID mi-contenedor-grafico en el archivo HTML donde quieres insertar el gráfico. Además, supone que la respuesta AJAX devuelve dos arrays: nombres y apellidos, donde cada elemento del array nombres corresponde con el elemento en la misma posición del array apellidos.

En este caso, cada rectángulo que se añade al gráfico representa un elemento de los datos. La posición x del rectángulo se calcula multiplicando el índice del elemento en el array datos por 50. La posición y del rectángulo se calcula restando el valor del campo apellido del elemento del valor total de la altura del gráfico (500 en este caso). La altura del rectángulo se establece igual al valor del campo apellido del elemento.

Por lo tanto, si el array datos tiene los valores {juan,pedro,gabriel} y {5,10,3}, se añadirían al gráfico tres rectángulos en las posiciones x 50, 100 y 150, con alturas de 5, 10 y 3 respectivamente.

Este es un ejemplo muy básico y no es necesario seguirlo al pie de la letra. Puedes modificar el código para adaptarlo a tus necesidades y a la estructura de tus datos.